# Angular JS and Web Sockets

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, pug

I am trying to get Angular JS working with web sockets, and after getting a basic set up from Angular web socket seed on Github, I am still facing a little problem with two way data binding. I am using a file like a config file, to set initial app values, which contains this:

```
  socket.emit('button:state', {
    state: 'default'
  });
```

Then I have a controller that deals with the state of the button initially, and then attempts to rewrite the initial state via the web socket:

```
function MyCtrl1($scope, socket) {

    // UI INITIAL STATE
    socket.on('button:state', function (data) {
        $scope.buttonState = data.state;
    });

    // UI CLICKED STATE
    $scope.buttonClicked = function(data) {
        //$scope.buttonState = 'clicked';
        socket.emit('button:state', {
            state: 'clicked'
        });
        console.log('button clicked');
    };
}
MyCtrl1.$inject = ['$scope', 'socket'];
```

The view is simply set up in Jade:

```
div(class='button', ng-class='buttonState', ng-click='buttonClicked()')
```

Can anyone shed some light, please?

Comment: Nothing really obvious here. I often find that setting a default value before any other of something like `$scope.buttonState = ''` or is useful to initialize and also keep track of variables that I use for state.  Can you post the output of the Jade?

Answer (score 2):

You're not in Angular's RunLoop. Try to add `$scope.$apply();` after changing `buttonState` when you receive from the socket.